# How to Reset all Drivers to Factory Default

Tags: driver, defaults, mojave

I am trying to sync an Arduino board to my Mac and it was working fine until I installed some drivers.  Now it can't find the serial port.

How can I reset all drivers to the factory default?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a hardware issue: A current sensor was drawing too much power when connected to the 5V and ground pins on the board so it was being shut off automatically.